# Compacting/minifying dynamic html

Tags: html, django, compression, gzip

I am using django templating, and for readability I have html that looks similar to the following:

```
{% if some_variable %}
    text
{% else %}
    nothing exists here
{% endif %}

{% for item in set %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
...etc...
```

It converts to the following html at runtime, which includes tons of whitespace and returns:

```
text

<div>

  <li

        class='some_class

    >

    some text

   </li>

</div>

etc...
```

Some pages even run to ~3,000 lines of html when viewing the page source.

Is there a tool to compress this html at runtime? What about a tool to remove extra line breaks?

Comment: Google turned this up: http://www.soyoucode.com/2011/minify-html-output-django (I'm not familiar with Django, so I don't know if it's of any use in your particular case, though).

Comment: did you tried  django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware,

Comment: You probably want a Django/Python HTMLTidy approach.

Comment: For instance... http://utidylib.berlios.de/

Comment: I agree with @mrok. Just gzip your response. That will give you the lightest page load possible. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a bit of background, this is done intentionally, since Django's templating engine currently doesn't care about sanitizing lines that evaluate to blanks after the tags get stripped out and doing so will incur some minor performance penalties in serving the response, since it involves a post-processing step that evaluates the full contents of the rendered template.

Still, if you need a quick solution, I suggest you employ the [`StripWhitespaceMiddleware`](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware) response middleware that'll remove spurious whitespaces from textual responses. It's pretty fast and straightforward, employing regular expression matching like the templating engine itself. A more taxing, but powerful alternative would be deploy a response middleware that utilizes an HTML prettifier, if you really care about the poor human beings still reading raw responses.

Comment: There are other issues related to excessive whitespace than readability, such as bandwidth on sites with considerable concurrent requests, but that's usually to do with *bigger sites* like Yahoo, Facebook, etc. I agree with the spirit of your answer, though, in that whitespace bloat is typically an uglification problem that designers and non-IT executive types find "pwoblematic". The best case of this I've come across is the one where the *source markup* was judged by markup-no-nothings as representing the quality of the code. Funny what we put up with for a paycheck sometimes.

Comment: Designers, non-IT executive types and developers with OCPD ;)!

Answer (score 4):

[django-htmlmin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-htmlmin) package is a awesome, it provides a lot of control and features moreover it supports HTML 5.

Answer (score 2):

Looking around I just found django-pipeline, I just tried, by now, the middleware and it's just what I'm expected. It minify all html and text nodes and keep javascript nodes untouched.

Middleware implementation and basic test result is about 4 minutes, just pip install and activate the middleware after you gzip middleware or on top of your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting.

https://github.com/cyberdelia/django-pipeline

http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 2):

I think a front-end development tool, such as [`grunt-contrib-htmlmin`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin), should be used to minify Django template files before deploying them to production server.

This way, the minification process happens in "build-time", and saves server CPU resource for HTML minification in "run-time".

This tool is originally designed for minifying HTML, but also works for Django templates as I tried out.

Comment: Awesome, I was thinking about similar solution where minification could run on template load time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using with Nginx its Strip module is doing really great job with cleaning the html for you. It's real time and transparent. You don't need to care about at all after you set it up correctly.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStripModule

Answer (score 1):

"I think a front-end development tool, such as grunt-contrib-htmlmin, should be used to minify Django template files before deploying them to production server."

I had a need to do this some time ago to increase performance and decrease latency.  I wrote a template minimizer that will minimize the HTML, CSS, and Javascript in your templates beforehand so that the pages are composed minimized.  It integrates into Django as a Django command, understands the intricacies of the Django tempting language, and is extendable.  You can find it on pypi at the link below:

[django-template-minimizer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-template-minimizer)

Comment: This sounds great, but it is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a custom template loader [django-spaceless-templates](https://github.com/martinsvoboda/django-spaceless-templates), which strips unnecessary whitespace characters. This approach has two advantages:

- With the combination with cached template loader, whitespace stripping is done only once during template compilation. On the other hand with {% spaceless %} or middleware approach minification is called every time a template is rendered.
- Whitespace stripping can be more aggressive - remove spaces between HTML tags, Django tags and variables.