# How to remove white space from html source code

Tags: html, django

I am using django and python. In the template file, I have a drop-down list which is shown as below. It works. The only problem is that there is a lot of white space between  in the source html code. Is there any way to remove the white space? Thanks.

```
           {% for lang_ele in video.languages.all %}
              {% ifequal lang_ele.lang display_language  %}
                   {% for key, value in language_table.items %}
                       {% ifequal lang_ele.lang key%}
                         <option selected = "selected" value={{lang_ele.lang}}>{{value}}</option>
                       {% endifequal %}
                   {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
                   {% for key, value in language_table.items %}
                       {% ifequal lang_ele.lang key%}
                         <option value={{lang_ele.lang}}>{{value}}</option>
                       {% endifequal %}
                   {% endfor %}

              {% endifequal %}
           {% endfor %}
```

The output html souce code looks like this:

```
<option value=de>German</option> 


<option value=el>Greek</option> 


<option value=hi>Hindi</option>
```

Comment: You should try to accept more of your previous questions. It will give people more incentive to help you

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713464/compaacting-minifying-dynamic-html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the [`spaceless`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#spaceless) template tag. It:

> Removes whitespace **between** HTML tags.

```
{% spaceless %}
<p>
    <a href="foo/">Foo</a>
</p>
{% endspaceless %}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Look toward middelware, eg "htmlmin". It processes the file at a time. In addition it has a decorator.
   https://crate.io/packages/django-htmlmin
2. gzip will give the same effect. Probably would have cost to opt out of trimming.
   Look towards django middelware or nginx gzip.

   - django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware
   - http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule
3. You use the controller/model logic in the template. This is wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

I used custom helper function with stripping. Here is a an example I used too: https://web.archive.org/web/20140729182917/http://cramer.io/2008/12/01/spaceless-html-in-django/

Comment: Would you please add essential part to the answer (function code and how it could be used)? The link is broken.