# Django: best practice to minify HTML to improve page speed loading

Tags: django, django-templates

*Its about results in https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/*

Probably it is pretty much to just globally wrap whole HTML with `spaceless` template tag?

```
   {% spaceless %}
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      ...
   </html>
   {% endspaceless %}
```

Or it is not safe and there are some better ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a few options for this. After a quick search I found [`StripWhitespaceMiddleware`](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware) and another 3rd party app called [django-htmlmin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-htmlmin). You would need to make sure that these packages are compatible with your version of python and Django. Also, have a look at the solutions in [this question about HTML minification in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713464/compacting-minifying-dynamic-html).

Comment: django-htmlmin mentioned in this answer is implemented in Python and therefore not very fast. It also seems unmaintained. A modern implementation leveragin the Rust-based minify-html for Django is [django-minify-html](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-minify-html)

Answer (score 2):

**Two three solutions I've found:**

1. django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware
2. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule
3. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStripModule

Gzip should does the same thing - removes unnecessary white spaces before html delivered.

Comment: Gzip does not remove white space. HTML is compressed, send over the wire, and the browser decompresses the content. The browser ends up with a version that still has all white space. IE: A simple file with some white space is 214 Bytes, gzipped it is 47 bytes, removing the white space 10 bytes

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a custom template loader, which strips unnecessary whitespace characters. This approach has two advantages:

- With the combination with cached template loader, whitespace stripping is done only once during template compilation. On the other hand with {% spaceless %} or middleware approach minification is called every time a template is rendered.
- Whitespace stripping can be more aggressive - remove spaces between HTML tags, Django tags and variables.

After research, I find [django-template-minifying-loader](https://github.com/SectorLabs/django-template-minifying-loader) project, but it has several issues and it is unmaintained. You can use my own fork [django-spaceless-templates](https://github.com/martinsvoboda/django-spaceless-templates).

Answer (score -2):

You can try [Jinja2](https://medium.com/@samuh/using-jinja2-with-django-1-8-onwards-9c58fe1204dc), in some cases you can achieve tenfold speedup.

Check Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines) for more details.

Comment: It is not about server speed of template rendering, it is about final size of html document that delivers to users

Comment: https://www.dyspatch.io/blog/python-templating-performance-showdown-django-vs-jinja/